# Help on how to make a FNAF like camera system in game maker studio 2

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I'm trying to program a Five Nights at Freddy's type camera system. I already made the flip-up animation by clicking the button at the bottom of the screen but I have problems making it go over to the camera system where the camera buttons will be. I watched a tutorial and they used xview and yview but I read a comment that it won't work on newer versions, instead it would be something like `camera_set_view`. Also the camera appears behind the middle-room and not over it like it should be. Also you should only be able to look at the camera when your facing the window. Or is there a completely different way to do this?

https://imgur.com/a/u1LXnBy

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]